# MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser Multi-Object DiscoveryInfo

Tags: multipeer-connectivity

I do not understand how this makes sense. I put two objects in the discoveryinfo dictionary inside the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser object that I create and the browser doesn't see the advertiser, yet when I move the second object out of the dictionary and comment it out at the end of the line, the browser sees the advertiser. Does the discoveryinfo dictionary only accept one object to work? I have a string as the first object and an array as the second. Here is what it looks like:

```
advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:myPeerID discoveryInfo:@{@"Name": [[NSString alloc] initWithString:myUniqueID], @"Peers": [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:connectedPeersAry]} serviceType:@"Blahblah"];
```

And before that line, I tried this simpler format (but went to the above just in case the syntax was the problem):

```
advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:myPeerID discoveryInfo:@{@"Name": myUniqueID, @"Peers": connectedPeersAry} serviceType:@"FRCSCOUT"];
```

I guess I can put a dictionary or array inside the discoveryinfo dictionary, but I feel it's a pretty dumb way of doing things because a dictionary shouldn't ever be limited to one object for any case.

I'll go ahead and put my objects in another layer to "conserve space" inside the discoveryinfo dictionary, but if any of you find a better way of doing things or if you are seeing the same problem, please let me know.

Comment: Side question: why are you transmitting the list of connected peers in your advertisement?

Comment: I totally misunderstood the Multipeer Connectivity API at first. I had thought that the Advertiser role basically created a "Chat Room" of sorts and the Browser role asked to join, which isn't the way it was supposed to be. It was meant to be that the Advertiser basically says it's available to join a group and the Browser invites specific Browsers to the group. The reason why I had the list of connected peers was because I didn't want duplicates of data recording/sharing roles within my app in the same group of connected peers.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple objects in the `discoveryInfo` dictionary, but keep in mind that the dictionary will be encoded in a Bonjour TXT record. This imposes a few restrictions on what can be put into that dictionary.

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser/initWithPeer%3adiscoveryInfo%3aserviceType%3a) for `[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser initWithPeer:discoveryInfo:serviceType:]`:

> This data is advertised using a Bonjour TXT record, encoded according to RFC 6763 (section 6). As a result:
>
> - The key-value pair must be no longer than 255 bytes (total) when encoded in UTF-8 format with an equals sign (=) between the key and the value.
> - Keys cannot contain an equals sign.
>
> For optimal performance, the total size of the keys and values in this dictionary should be no more than about 400 bytes so that the entire advertisement can fit within a single Bluetooth data packet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found my problem. As quoted by Apple in their class reference for MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser:

> "The content of discoveryInfo will be advertised within Bonjour TXT records, so you should keep the dictionary small for better discovery performance."

So, looks like I'll have to use a comma separated string of some sort...

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the Multipeer Connectivity API. I thought the roles were reversed and the Advertiser was basically the public host for a Multipeer Session, but it should be the Browser that invites Advertisers. I now just have the Unique ID generated as the discovery info.

Thank you all for your help and sorry for the API confusion on my part.